# How to add an "edit comment" function (WordPress)?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm currently working with [site](https://weldzone.org/) on a WordPress with a [REHub plugin](https://themeforest.net/item/rehub-directory-multi-vendor-shop-coupon-affiliate-theme/7646339). We have a "leave a comment" section, everything was okay but our readers complain there's no way to edit comments. I tried to do this:

```
do_action('edit_comment', $comment_ID);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and it's impossible to edit comments.
Something wrong with the plugin or with my actions?

I tried to google similar questions from REHub users but haven't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Displays edit comment link using defaults.

<?php edit_comment_link(); ?> 

Displays edit comment link, with link text “edit comment”, in a paragraph () tag.
  
<?php edit_comment_link(__('edit comment'), '<p>', '</p>'); ?>
```